# Redirecting C++ generated cerr and cout to the same file in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, bash, cout, stderr, redirect

My program generates output both directed to std::cout and std::cerr. When I run a test file normally as in

```
./a.out <source> &> <target>
```

target captures both types of output in the order produced by ./a.out.

When trying to automate testing of output for a simple unit testing framework, I implemented the above in a bash script:

```
 `rm $OUT_NAME`
 `./a.out $NEW_UNIT &> $OUT_NAME`
```

(with the obvious variable names). The output sent to cout is printed fine; but the one sent to cerr is printed incorrectly (some is printed; then printing stops with no error). In case you wonder, I added the 'rm' first just to be perfectly sure it's no issue with over-writing/appending to an old version.

Any ideas?

My system:
Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In bash, you should do the following:

```
./a.out source > target 2>&1
```

to merge `stderr` into `stdout`.  The command you gave is meant for `csh`.

And if you want to merge `stdout` into `stderr`, you will do

```
./a.out source 2> target 1>&2
```

Comment: for the second part you probably mean to merge stdout into stderr?

Answer (score 4):

`./a.out source >> target 2>&1` would solve your problem
`2>&1` means that combine(or called redirect) standard error (stderr) with standard out (stdout) 
`>>` means to attach the output stream of your program to then end of "target". And if you use a single `>` instead of `>>`, it means to replace the output stream of your program with the "target".

P.S. 
Suppose your code have two different output 
 `std::cout<<"results"<<endl` 
and some `std::cerr<<"debug information"<<endl`

In bash, you can do  `./a.out source 1>>Result.txt 2>> Debug.txt` 
And your "**results**" would be store in Result.txt and your "**debug information**" would be store in Debug.txt.
`1>>` means standard output redirect to the back of somewhere, you can also use `1>` which means standard out redirect to somewhere 
 
`2>>` means standard error redirect to the back of somewhere, you can also use `2>` which means standard error redirect to somewhere

That would be very useful if you want to use script automatically run your program.

Answer (score 2):

In bash, this should work:

```
./a.out source >target 2>&1
```

Comment: this actually will not work as you need to redirect `2>&1`  after `> target`

Comment: @noonex, I have been using it incorrectly for a long time and didn't realize the error. Thanks.